# How to add addresses to line segments in road network files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reverse-geocoding

I have road network data for incorporated/unincorporated places in the US. Each place is composed of road network lines with the following attributes: street name, length, place name, State.

I would like to add start/end address attributes to the lines; however, I cannot find a data sources. Does such a source exist? Or is it possible to reverse geocode?